# TimeComplexity of the following merging k linked lists

Tags: c, merge, linked-list, time-complexity

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-linked-lists/

**With reference to the link:** 
How does the divide and conquer strategy gives O(nk Log k) complexity please explain.
Also,I have coded the same in a little bit different way. The only difference being in the pattern of merging. I merge the first 2 linked result and then their result with the other linked list.

**What will be the complexity of this?**

```
Node * mergek(){
    int n;
    puts("Enter number of linked list you want to enter");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    Node ** arr=malloc(sizeof(Node *)*n);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i] = takeInput();
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        print(arr[i]);
    }
    Node * temp=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i==0){
            temp=merge(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
            i=i+1;
        }   
        else{
            temp=merge(arr[i],temp);
        }   
    }
    return temp;    
}
```

**I wanted to know if this will have the same complexity or no i e. O(nklog(k)) complexity.**

The number of merges remain same.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do a merge, because you haven't shown your `merge()` code. All we know is that it is `O(n) * O(merge)`

Answer (score 0):

While the number of merges remain the same, the pattern of merging actually makes the time complexity a lot worse. Assuming you have a `merge()` function to [merge two sorted linked lists](https://chinocode.com/Merging-Two-Sorted-Linked-Lists/) in `O(n + m)` time (where n = size of first list, m = size of second) and `O(1)` space, consider the following analysis in which I assume each list has on average `n` elements.

- First merge will be `O(n + n)`, as we're merging two `n`-sized lists
- Second merge will be `O(2n + n)`, as we're merging one `n`-sized list with our now `2n`-sized list
- Third merge will be `O(3n + n)`...and so on.

At this point we have to add up all of the additions inside the Big-Oh to get:

```
O(2n + 3n + 4n + 5n + ... + kn)
```

The sum of all these `n` terms is essentially `n*(k(k+1))/2` because `(k(k+1))/2` is the sum of the first `k` numbers. By taking the constant factors and lower order terms out of `(k(k+1))/2`, we can see that `O((k(k+1))/2) = O(k^2)`, thus giving the algorithm `O(n*k^2)` time complexity.

I wrote a small article on this problem and analyzed further, the extent of the complexity differences. You should check it out **[here](https://chinocode.com/Merging-K-Sorted-Arrays-and-Linked-Lists/)**

---

To answer your other question on how does the divide and conquer approach actually yield O(nk*log(k)), think of how merge sort works.

If we have $n$ items, merge sort does `n` amount of work, as many times as it takes to pairwise merge `n` items together before they become one whole list. This number is `log(n)` (log base 2 of n), thus it takes a number of steps proportional to `nlog(n)` (again, realize we're doing `n` amount of work because there are always `n` elements at play, `log(n)` times). The reason merge sort has to break a list down into individual elements before merging them is because a single unit is the smallest thing we can get that is by definition, sorted, without us doing any work to sort it.

In our case, each list is already sorted, so we can treat each of the `k` lists (of size ~n) as an element sorted by definition. There is no need to break a sorted list down any further. Since there are `k` lists each with `n` elements, there will always be `n*k` elements at play. Luckily since each list is already sorted though, we only have to merge `k` "elements" together instead of all `n*k` list elements. So the same logic prevails, in that we have to merge `k` elements/lists together. Since each list takes `O(n)` time to merge, as opposed to `O(1)` when dealing with `n*k` individual elements, it takes time proportional to `O(nk*log(k))`.